# Unable to perform the actions on already installed app in android

Tags: mobile, android, appium

I am trying to execute code as shown below. But the error prompted is

`[org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:]A new session could not be created. (No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device)`

I have installed an app and trying to perform some actions like entering the username, password etc. But I am unable to do that.

However, when I include

`File app = new File("apk location"), caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath())`

I am able to execute the code.

But I am unable to perform actions on the already installed app. Can anybody provide the solution?

```
@BeforeClass

public void configurationSettings() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
    caps.setCapability("packageName", "com.example.hybridtestapp");
    caps.setCapability("activityName", "com.example.hybridtestapp.MainActivity");
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
}

@Test
public void hybridAppFunc(){
    List <WebElement> all = driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.EditText");
    all.get(0).sendKeys("appium user");
}

@AfterClass
public void closeApp(){
    driver.closeApp();
}
```

Comment: Does it open app properly? and do you getting any error/exception?

Comment: No, the exception is as follows [org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException:]A new session could not be created. (No app set; either start appium with --app or pass in an 'app' value in desired capabilities, or set androidPackage to launch pre-existing app on device)" which is stated in the above ticket

Comment: I can able to execute the test-case when I include the two instructions         i) "File app = new File("apk location")                                                           ii) caps.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath())"                                     where it will open the app and type the username and password, but I want to execute the same test-case with app already installed. Let me know the solution anybody

Comment: Are the desired capability parameters correct? And which version of appium are you using?

Comment: yes they are correct, appium ver:1.4

Comment: Anybody there to answer my question. I want to perform some set of actions in android using appium with a condition that the app is already installed. Please answer

Comment: are you able to use the Android Driver to perform actions on the already installed app?? Any solution on this is much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `appPackage` and `appActivity` in your Desired Capabilities instead of `packageName` and `activityName`.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();  
caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Android");  
caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");  
caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");  
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.example.hybridtestapp");  
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.example.hybridtestapp.MainActivity");  
driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
```