# How do I test on an already-installed Android application using Appium + Selenium?

Tags: appium

I am using the APK info app to know what activities' name are:

```
  package name.v2.acyivities.SplashActivity

  package name.v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion
```

(...)

And then I create the DesiredCapabilities:

```
public AndroidDriver remoteRunningDevice() throws  Exception {

    DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("platformName", MobileConfig.platformName);

    cap.setCapability("deviceName", MobileConfig.emulatorDeviceName);

    cap.setCapability("platformVersion", MobileConfig.emulatorPlatformVersion);

    cap.setCapability("app-package", MobileConfig.appPackage);
    cap.setCapability("appActivity","MobileConfig.appPackage" +".v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion");
    cap.setCapability("noSign", true);

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(MobileConfig.url), cap);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return driver;
}
```

But it can't be run and result is:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Do you also have the stacktrace? On what line does the NullPointerException occur?

Comment: i tested on an already installed Android application and remeber application status by running cmd:

Comment: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone --log G:/log_appium.txt

Comment: But i can't run this command bu using java Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); final Process pr = rt.exec(APPIUMSERVERSTARTCMD);

Comment: Someone said add "cmd /c " before that command but it do not work

Comment: Checkout this thread: http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/14852/unable-to-perform-the-actions-on-already-installed-app-in-android/14879#14879

Answer (score 0):

```
public AndroidDriver driver;

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.android();
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", deviceName);
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "android");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, osVersion);
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "YOUR PACKAGE NAME");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "MainActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("app", appPath);     

driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:"+port2+"/wd/hub"),capabilities);
```

you can use UIAutomator to find your package name. Device name and OS version can be found using 'adb devices'

Comment: i tested on an already installed Android application and remeber application status by running cmd: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node.exe" "C:/Program Files (x86)/Appium/node_modules/appium/bin/Appium.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone --log G:/log_appium.txt

Comment: But i can't run this command bu using java Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); final Process pr = rt.exec(APPIUMSERVERSTARTCMD) . Someone said add "cmd /c " before but it not work

Comment: `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);`

Comment: `public String getPort() {
    ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0);
    socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    String port = Integer.toString(socket.getLocalPort());
    socket.close();
    return port;  }
    
    public void runCommand(){
    String port = ap.getPort();
    String chromePort = ap.getPort();
    String bootstrapPort = ap.getPort();
    String command = "appium --session-override -p "+port+" --chromedriver-port "+chromePort+" -bp "+bootstrapPort;
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

in your code:

```
    cap.setCapability("app-package", MobileConfig.appPackage);
    cap.setCapability("appActivity","MobileConfig.appPackage" +".v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion");
```

You are using `MobileConfig.appPackage` to get the package name, for example if the package name stored on `MobileConfig.appPackage` is 'com.example', the desired capability is somethings like `app-package=com.example`

What I am pointing here is the second line, when setting capabilities for `appActivity` which is you are using: `"MobileConfig.appPackage" +".v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion"`. The `"MobileConfig.appPackage"` will be considered as String, so the capability will become like:

```
appActivity=MobileConfig.appPackage.v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion
```

This will lead to app Activity not found, since the package name is different (may causing the Null pointer, but I am not sure). I assume that you want to make the capability is more like:

```
appActivity=com.example.v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion
```

the capability should be like this one:

```
    cap.setCapability("appActivity", MobileConfig.appPackage + ".v2.acyivities.OnBoardingChooseRegion");
```

Write the `MobileConfig.appPackage` without quotes. Hope this will help to find the clue.